# Could we compose different Redux applications to create a bigger one?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was building a redux application but the scope has changed so now I have to move my app inside another one that it's a redux application as well.

This looks something like:

```
<MainApp >
  <components />
  <MyApp props={myAppProps} />
</MainApp>
```

The main problem I found is how to deal with property changes with myApp's store.

So my doubts are:

- Is there a proper way to handle different redux apps?
- How could we split a huge app so we can develop its different parts independently?

Comment: What is the problem that you have? I don’t understand what “how to deal with property changes with myApp's store” means. Can you show a specific example you are struggling with?

Comment: Let's say I have an app that can handle files and edit its content. So I have 2 apps, one is the main one that handle the files and the other is the editor itself.
`<MainApp><Editor content={fileContent} /></MainApp>`
The main app will pass the content of the file to the editor but the editor has it's own store based on this file. This store can handle what is the caret's position, and things like that but the Main App won't be aware of this. In fact, MainApp can change the content of the editor and the that store will be reset.

Comment: @DanAbramov Maybe my answer explains better the situation. But I'm not sure the `<Provider />` can handle that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187722/could-we-compose-different-redux-applications-to-create-a-bigger-one/38188580#38188580

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is actually a Redux App in your opinion?

Redux is just a data management solution for your application:

If you have a two sets of reducers created with `combineReducers()`

```
rootReducerForApp = combineReducers({reducer1, reducer2, reducer3});
rootReducerForSomeThingElse = combineReducers({r1, r2, ...});
```

you could combine those and have a one reducer for your app

```
combindedRootReducer = combineReducers({
  rootReducerForApp,
  rootReducerForSomeThingElse
})
```

then create your single Store with

`let store = createStore(combinedRootReducer)`

Now you can use all the actions you need for both of your semantically separated *app-parts* from the same place

Comment: Yes, that makes sense but it's not a complete solution. How do you deal with actions for instance. I assume that we should pass down the store to every subApplication so then they can dispatch actions to the main store.
I think that could work.

Comment: @carlesba all your actions will be passed to all your reducers.. like usual

Answer (score 1):

Here comes a possible solution. Let's say we have an application that uses an Editor. Both are different apps but the **MainApp** can pass the file to edit to the **Editor**. The components will look like this:

```
<MainApp>
  <Editor
     content={fileContent}
     author={fileAuthor}
     onSubmitFile={(f) => updateFile(f)}
   />
</MainApp>
```

So MainApp and Editor will have different reducers, stores and actions.

The problem is how to handle Editor's store changes so everything. The way to solve it could be on React's lifecycle. We could create the store when `Editor` gets mounted and update parts of their store based on the new props.

Something like:

```
const Editor = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount() {
    const initialData = {...this.props} // pick whatever data we need from props
    this.store = createStore(initialData) // create initial Store
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    const {content, author} = nextProps
    this.store.dispatch(setAuthor(author))
    this.store.dispatch(setContent(content))
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <EditorContainers />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: Yea, this is definitely a solution. However if these apps share the same data, it might be easier to export a reducer from the subapp and have a single store instead. Up to you which way to use; both works.

Comment: this solves a particular case but my question was more about how do you scale an app that has many apps inside with their own stores, reducers, actions… Not sure how can we import from many subApps.

Comment: I don’t see the kind problem with importing. If you can create a new question just about that **demonstrating the problem** maybe I could help. It’s very hard to help when the question is “not sure if X would work”. Try and see :-)

Comment: Should be easy to provide the store and the actions from the subApp into the globalApp, and the globalApp could be or not a redux app (with a global state and their own reducers), and compose the subApp store in their store. That make sense? @carlesba

Comment: @davesnx yes, indeed I guess the purpose of redux is to get a single store so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to have a subapp with its own `<Provider />`

Example:

```
let store1 = createStore(reducers);
let store2 = createStore(otherReducers);


const RootApp = () => (
  <Provider store={store1}>
    <MainApp />
  </Provider>
)
const MainApp = () => (
  <div>
    <SomeMainAppComponent /> {/* This will receive store1 as context */}

    <Provider store={store2}>
      <EditorApp /> {/* This will receive store2 as context */}
    </Provider>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: this was my first approach but that doesn't scale well. It breaks the main reason of Redux that is having only one source of true.